# Auto bug Filling by Processing or Scraping log file (Java Application)

Tags: java, logging, jira, bugzilla

I have Java Application (Apache Karaf and Tomcat and Web Application). Each one of the module logs into /var/log/[module]/[module].log file.  I would like to have some watchdog or agent that would process log file while server is running and automatically file a bug for each exception in log file.  (The bug tracking system is Bugzila or Jira). Is there anything available like this off-shelf?

I appreciate your feedback and input.  Thanks !

Comment: what should happen if an exception is hit multiple times? Create a new bug-report (for the same error-case) each time? Not sure if [logentries](https://logentries.com/) is capable of doing this, it can however send exceptions via mail and post them to slack if configured.

Comment: For now it can just count.